# Remove parenthesis and text in parenthesis using REGEXREPLACE in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, replace, match

I have a cell containing a text string like this:

```
A1 = John (John started 1/1/2020)
```

I'd like to remove everything in parenthesis so the end result would be:

```
A1 = John
```

I am trying to use REGEXREPLACE and I have the following formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\(([A-Za-z]+)\)","")
```

However, this is not working.  How do I remove the parenthesis and everything inside?  The text in the parenthesis will vary, but will always be inside parenthesis.

For additional context - The above formula does work on a cell with a text string like this:

```
A2 = William (Bill)
```

When I use the above formula on cell A2, I get this:

```
A2 = William
```

Why does it work on A2 but not A1?

Comment: It's because A contains space, slash, and numbers while your regex defined only upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, " \((.+)\)", )))
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to do this if A1 == "John (John stared 1/12020)" (so in reverse)? The formula doesn't acknowledge this scenario.

Comment: @WilliamToscano not sure what do you mean by "reverse" can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: So in your screen shot, A1 is "John (John started in 1/12020)" and the formula works for that scenario. But is there a formula that works where A1 would equal "(John started in 1/12020) John", so I just flipped the 2 substrings around. The substring inside parentheses comes first, then " John".

Comment: Here is a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzsw2M2CzQNLOiwFEQOmmwFx5gmAmnLgOdv60npFBI0/edit#gid=0

Comment: @WilliamToscano try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4, "\(.*\) (.*)")))`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in being able to replace any number of sub-strings surrounded by parentheses, there's another posting here: [Google sheets - How to remove ALL the parenthesis with text inside in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987849/google-sheets-how-to-remove-all-the-parenthesis-with-text-inside-in-a-cell)

In that post, the regexreplace formula is used as follows:

```
=regexreplace(A1, "(\s\(.*?\))",)
```

to make a string like

```
we can (or can we...) replace multiple (try it) sub-strings with other text
```

become:

```
we can replace multiple sub-strings with other text
```

I was searching for this solution for a while, so I figured I'd post it here to make it that much easier to find.