# Google sheets - How to remove ALL the parenthesis with text inside in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For example i have this in the G33 cell:

> Hello (example) world (example 2). How are you (example 3) ?

And i want to remove ALL of the 3 parenthesis with their texts so it becomes:

> Hello world. How are you?

I have found some functions but they only remove the first parenthesis.

I want a function that will remove every parenthesis with their contents that exists on a cell.

Can someone provide me with one? I am a begginer in google sheets so my knowledge on functions is very restricted. so please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=regexreplace(G33, "(\s\(.*?\))",)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is sufficient to remove a single level of parenthesis:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"\([^()]*\)","")
```

[image]

Replacing nested brackets appears challenging, but as a workaround you can nest the function to arbitrary depth like this:

```
=regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"\([^()]*\)",""),"\([^()]*\)","")
```

This assumes that the brackets are correctly matched. You could run a quick check like this:

```
=len(substitute(A1,"(",""))=len(substitute(A1,")",""))
```

which at least checks that you have as many right brackets as left ones, but again checking that they are correctly matched would be more difficult.